# (Swift/iOS) Is it possible to get user purchased items from In app purchases?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8, in-app-purchase

I have a store view inside my app that lists all the available products for a user to buy, the thing is that I want to disable those products that has been already purchased by the user, is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't.

It's up to you to manage this information. You can do this the easy way locally using NSUserDefaults and restoring purchases (for new devices).

Or the lengthier way - storing all purchases on your server.

Comment: if I use NSUserDefaults is there a way that the user can access and modify the contents?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is a small scale storage bin with space exclusively defined for your app and can't be read from others.

Comment: So, no. Not unless you write a GUI that allows them to

Comment: It is a shame that apple does not keep track of the purchased items like the Windows Store does via isActive

Comment: I agree with you. Relying on local storages allows a fraudulent person to manipulate what they have purchases or not. Relying on server is not 100% because network can go down at any time. There is no hybrid solution that will work all the time! User can in those exceptions lose purchases if they are consumables (no restore option)